# Retrofit Nested GET Request in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit` in my application. I need to call two Web Service to set data to `RecyclerView`.I get `JSONArray` from first `GET` call. The format is

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "W",
        "myId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "W",
        "myId": 1
    }
]
```

I need to get `myId` from this `JSONObject` and need to call another Web Service as `http://www.example.com/api/myInfo/myId` to get another response. As the second Web Service call is dependent on 1st and I want to get the data at the same time and set to `RecyclerView` adapter. At this moment I am calling the service as

```
getCalls.getInfo().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<QueuePojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<QueuePojo>> call, Response<ArrayList<QueuePojo>> response)
            {
                entry=response.body();
                adapter=new QueueAdapter(entry,MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<QueuePojo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

How to make such dependent calls in Retrofit and at last set data to RecyclerView Adapter?

Comment: How can you get it at same time when the second one depends on the response of the first  one ? You have to execute them sequentially and set the adapter in the response of second api call

Comment: So i need to make second request in the first request, using the id, make another call parse the response and set to adapter . is  it so ?

Comment: yes that's what you have to do